# Why does my command line not able to process global commands even though I've installed the package globally?

Tags: npm, webpack

I cannot run `webpack --help` inside an arbitrary directory, I get the following error:

```
One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): o
You need to install 'webpack-cli' to use webpack via CLI.
You can also install the CLI manually.
```

Which I clearly did with both `npm` and `yarn`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed webpack-cli globally with npm?

```
npm install --global webpack-cli
```

If so, can you verify this with the command `which webpack-cli` ?

Comment: does this behavior get suppressed if a `node_module` dire is detected in the execution dir?